# What circuits can blink an LED at certain power consumption threshold?

Tags: transistors, power, led, analog, shunt

I have never designed an analog circuit and I am requested to design an analog circuit where a LED driven by a transistor must start blinking at a given frequency when the input power is above a certain threshold. The suggestion is to use a shunt resistor to measure the current. Do you think this is possible without using programmable ICs (regular ICs are allowed)?

Are there any circuits you can think of that could do this?

Comment: Comparator + 555?

Comment: "a given frequency when the input power" does what?

Comment: @jonathanjo I think it's supposed to be "a given frequency determined by input power".  (Maybe slow when above a minimum threshold and faster at a higher threshold?)

Comment: I am so sorry I meant when the input power is above a certain threshold, solution by @Voltage Spike is still valid, I am looking into it, but I'm not sure if it can be extended to what I'd like to implement since the frequency is proportional to the voltage. I basically want the LED to blink above a power threshold and shut down below another specified threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you would need to measure power, that can be done with an opamp. You then pipe that output to a V to F circuit

Here is a circuit to measure current (if the voltage is fixed to the load it is also a measure of power)
[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/fundamentals-of-current-measurement-part-2-current-sense-amplifiers

V to F can be done with an opamp and a comparator (with a switch/fet to null out the capacitor voltage and let it recharge), this is the basic idea:

[image]
Source: https://www.asdlib.org/onlineArticles/elabware/Scheeline_ADC/ADC_ADC_V2F.html

Here are two 'monolitic' solutions:

[image]
https://www.eeweb.com/low-cost-voltage-to-frequency-converter/

Yeah, linear timer blocks. 0 to 1V in, a frequency out.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for giving so many references to look into. I did not know where to start, and this answer really get me started accomplishing results.